# Create column with update statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Is it possible to create a row with an update statement if it not exists? I am using java with mysql and i want to save some user data. If the user does not already have a row it should be created.

Comment: I don't think a user should have a "column", maybe you mean a row? If you really mean a column, your database structure isn't done properly.

Comment: sorry, you are right. i mean a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will create rows with the "insert" statement, not the update statement.

If you have a unique index on your user_id on your table, you can use this :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `mytable`
SET `user_id` = 'value', `column` = 'value';
```

With the ignore keyword, if the row exists already, it will do nothing. If it doesn't, it will insert it.

**This only works if there is a unique key that prevents the insertion of duplicates in your table.**

If you don't use that method, you need to select in the table to see if there is a record, and if not, insert it. But this would require two queries.

Comment: what is if there are columns that are not affected by the query? what will their value be? Eg if there are the columns 'a, b, c' and i only insert into a and b

Comment: It will be null, unless you specified a "default value" on the column that is not set to anything.